# Several identical dictionaries component mean

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, functional-programming, average

I have several Python3 dictionaries with the same identical structure, mapping string labels to real values. For example, for 4 entries, the data set could look like:

> {"a": 1.2, "b": 3.2, "c":5.65}

> {"a": 2.5, "b": 3.8, "c":9.65}

> {"a": 2.8, "b": 3.2, "c":2.65}

> {"a": 1.8, "b": 1.2, "c":3.65}

I want to do a component wise average of this components, so the final result should look like:

> {"a": 2.07, "b": 2.85, "c":5.4}

I know how to resolve the problem using for-loops with adding up the values and divide each entry by the count at the end, like

```
def final_results(scores):
result = {}
for score in scores:
    for k, v in score.items():
        if k not in result:
            result[k] = v
        else:
            result[k] += v
for k, v in result:
    result[k] = v / len(scores)
return result
```

, but I'm looking for a way to solve the problem in a functional way, using lambda, map, filter etc. Is there any?

Comment: Aside: have you considered using e.g. Pandas? That could fit your problem better, even if it's not directly functional.

Comment: I already have a lot of dependencies, so I would avoid adding another one, but that would be a solution if no "plain" one is available

Comment: Well, with a Pandas DataFrame, you'd probably do `df.mean(axis=0)` to get the mean for each column.

Comment: would look into the Pandas solution. still curious for a *plain* python3 one, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a list of dicts:

```
data = [{'a': 1.2, 'b': 3.2, 'c': 5.65},
        {'a': 2.5, 'b': 3.8, 'c': 9.65}, 
        {'a': 2.8, 'b': 3.2, 'c': 2.65}, 
        {'a': 1.8, 'b': 1.2, 'c': 3.65}]
```

A somewhat functional one-liner in plain Python (excluding the `itertools` import) could be:

```
from itertools import reduce

{key: value / len(data) for key, value in 
 reduce(lambda item1, item2: {key: value + item2[key] 
            for key, value in item1.items()}, 
        data, 
        {key: 0 for key in data[0]}).items()}
```

which gives

```
{'a': 2.075, 'b': 2.8499999999999996, 'c': 5.3999999999999995}
```

---

Using Pandas, you could do the following:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

DataFrame(data).mean()
```

which results in

```
a    2.075
b    2.850
c    5.400
dtype: float64
```

Technically a Pandas Series, hence the included dtype in its output. If you like to convert that result to a dict as above, use:

```
DataFrame(d).mean().to_dict()
```

to get

```
{'a': 2.075, 'b': 2.8499999999999996, 'c': 5.3999999999999995}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also a library solution from `toolz`:

```
from toolz import merge_with

d1 = {"a": 1.2, "b": 3.2, "c":5.65}
d2 = {"a": 2.5, "b": 3.8, "c":9.65}
d3 = {"a": 2.8, "b": 3.2, "c":2.65}
d4 = {"a": 1.8, "b": 1.2, "c":3.65}

merge_with(lambda args: sum(args)/len(args), d1, d2, d3, d4)
```

It's pure Python in the sense that library has no external dependencies.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not answer the question since I asked for pure-python solutions.